# How to load test a complete logical flow using jmeter?

Tags: performance, jmeter, benchmarking

I have three APIs:

1. Create a user (returns userId in response body)
2. Add photo corresponding to user created in step 1 (takes userId in request body - same as obtained in response of first body)
3. Poll the API to check whether user photo updation is done (takes userId in request body - same as obtained in response of first body)

Running of these three APIs constitutes one logical flow of the application. 
I want to run and benchmark this 'set' of three APIs. 
I have following concerns in this regard:

How should I decide whether to have three different thread groups to run these 3 APIs or a single thread group should suffice ?

What should be used to extract 'userID' from first API response and use it as an input to second request.

How can I implement polling mechanism as needed in third API ?

If I have say 5 users hitting request1 and then the same 5 users hitting request 2, how can I establish mapping between requests so that user1 by first API gets mapped to second API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `How should I decide whether to have three different thread groups to run these 3 APIs or a single thread group should suffice ?` - I would go for a single [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) as it assumes actions of a single virtual user (or a group of virtual users)
2. `What should be used to extract 'userID' from first API response and use it as an input to second request.` - depending on the response type, [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/) for JSON, [XPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) for XML
3. `How can I implement polling mechanism as needed in third API ?` - using [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)
4. `If I have say 5 users hitting request1 and then the same 5 users hitting request 2, how can I establish mapping between requests so that user1 by first API gets mapped to second API ?` - you don't need to do anything, each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes [samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down and all the context like variables is [local to this user (thread)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage)